# Tumblr Post on Facebook does not include Post Contents

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, tumblr, facebook-opengraph

My blog: blog.go-jewellery.com, a tumblr blog, when I try to share posts, on facebook by either:

1. posting links - e.g. a post from my blog: http://blog.go-jewellery.com/post/19451387150/veg-out-london-borough-market-taken-with
2. using facebook sharing button at my post level

It will never pull in the post content, image, to be posted onto facebook. All it pulls in is the blog url.

Is it possible to include the contents from the post, when posting on Facebook?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You are using "share" which [got deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) in favor of the like button.

Comment: I would still recommend using share over like button, not all likes get turned into wall stories, which is not an issue for shares.

Comment: Also from an aesthetic perspective - I don't think a "like" button allows you to change the way the button looks, only a share button will allow for that.

Comment: Using deprecated methods is not good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is working now so I'm guessing you figured it out! You can always debug this using Facebook Debugger tool, putting your URL in gives:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.go-jewellery.com%2Fpost%2F19451387150%2Fveg-out-london-borough-market-taken-with

All the OG meta tags are correct. For anyone else looking at this, I recommend reading: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/ .

Comment: Hey it is not working still - if you try another post: http://blog.go-jewellery.com/post/19398563856/do-it-friday-flourless-beet-chocolate-cupcakes it does not work for sharing?

Comment: Heya Arturnt, It is very weird. If I pass my individual blog URLs to the Facebook debugger, after passing it, it will post properly on Facebook. Otherwise it would not work.

Comment: I tried out a bunch of links on your site and they all seem to be working correctly. Nice blog btw :).

Comment: Heya Artumt - thanks for the compliments! Hmmmph... but I don't know why it is working for you and not for me. Have you tried posting a blog post on to your facebook page to see how the link pops up, cos it is always blank for me... :(

Comment: Heya Artumt - sorry to bombard you again... but it is working for me now.. I have flushed the cache... I still don't know what the root cause was but am glad all is working. Yes and I did read the developer facebook docs prior to posting this question. :) Not sure why it is working now... but could also be code updates that I have done, that just got "updated" in the facebook server. Time lag I suppose.